# Robocopy CLI syntax won't work

Tags: windows, cmd, robocopy

I just recently saw that xcopy is deprecated and that Robocopy is recommended.

I tried moving files with it, but couldn't get it to work.

I tried moving files from `C:\Downloads\Temp` to `F:\Temp`
Both folders had no files directly under them. Downloads\Temp has about 20 folders, some of which have subfolders, which are eventually filled with files.

With the following syntax, it didn't work:

```
robocopy C:\Downloads\Temp F:\Temp /move
```

So I tried giving a wildcard for files:

```
robocopy C:\Downloads\Temp F:\Temp * /move
```

Didn't work either. I ended up doing it with xcopy, no problem.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?

I'm on Windows Vista Enterprise SP1, as administrator(CMD was also run as administrator)

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > With the following syntax, it didn't work:
> >     robocopy C:\Downloads\Temp F:\Temp /move

Yes - this says move all files from `c:\downloads\temp` to `f:\temp` - only files **directly** in those directories.

You need the **`/S`** switch to say "recursively down the directory stack":

```
robocopy C:\Downloads\Temp F:\Temp /S /move
```

Marc